# Nested hash in redis

Tags: ruby, hash, redis

I want to use a hash of hash (nested hash). For example,

```
{Key 1 -> 
  {Subkey 1 -> {Value1, Value2...}, 
    Subkey 2 -> {Value1, Value2...},
    .
    .
    Subkey n -> {Value1, Value2...}
  }
  Key 2 -> {...}
  .
  .
  Key n -> {...}
}
```

Tell me how I can define this structure in redis and also how to access these values. I am trying to use this on ruby.

Comment: As far as I know redis does not support nested hash with the Hash data structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can't use nested hash in redis, 
but in the kind of situation you are asking you can use two hashes, one for key to subkey 
and the other one for subkey to your values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store and retrieve them and you don't need the hash functions in Redis, you can just serialize the subhashes (e.g. Marshal, JSON, YAML).

Otherwise consider a different key-value database, like MongoDB; or @whishky's answer.